SharePoint Online Library - How to navigate straight to a New Document Set, rather than the Library after creation
I'm trying to see if there's a way to navigate a user directly to a newly created document set, rather than the Library view after creation.  Basically when a user fills out the SP Default form, clicks Submit, I want them to be navigated directly to that newly created document set.  Currently, the User stays in the Library after creating the new doc set - so they have an extra click to open the new doc set.  I'm trying to eliminate a step for them.  Is this possible?

Are you using SharePoint online?
I tested it in my environment and it didn't happen like yours. After creating a Document Set, you will directly enter the Document Set without clicking. I suggest you recreate the site and try again.
If the problem persists, please provide more details.

Thank you for the response.  I created a new Library, added the content type, created a new document set, but it still kept me in the Library after creating it, rather than navigating to the document set.  Is there a setting I'm forgetting about?  Yes this is SP Online
